# Как подключить свою собранную библиотеку в проект с помощью cmake?

Tags: c, cmake, библиотеки

Я скомпилировал свою статическую библиотеку, как подключить ее в проект с помощью cmake?
Я прописал в cmake `target_link_libraries(test /home/anton/dev/testtresh/untitled2/cmake-build-debug/libmath.a)`, но выдается ошибка

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "untitled2" which is not built by
  this project.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите документацию https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html.

Надо указывать таргеты. Если исполняемый это `test`, а библиотека `lib`, то

```
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE lib)
```

Comment: Исполняемый - это сама статическая библиотека .o, а lib - то дирретктория, где содержатся .h файлы?

Comment: @DenverToha нет, это оба таргеты. `add_executable(test)`, `lib` получена с помощью `find_library` или `add_library`

Comment: Я не могу понять, как получить lib, если мой библиотека находится по пути /home/anton/dev/testtresh/untitled2/cmake-build-debug/libmath.a

Comment: @DenverToha как вы получили эту библиотеку? Как в прошлом вопросе с помощью `add_library(lib)`? Тогда у вас уже есть `lib`

Comment: Я понимаю, но я хочу подключить библиотеку в другой проект, а не в тот же самый

Comment: @DenverToha тогда `find_library`